# Replace x + I y by z in complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Say I define

```
z = x + I y;
```

Then I calculate

```
-2 Im[z] + 3 + I(2 Re[z]) // ComplexExpand
```

which gives

```
3 + 2 I x - 2 y
```

How can I replace x + I y by z to get the equivalent 2 I z + 3 ?

As in

```
3 + 2 I x - 2 y == 2 I z + 3 //Simplify
(* True *)
```

Comment: `3 + 2 I x - 2 y /. {x -> (w + Conjugate[w])/2, 
   y -> (w - Conjugate[w])/(2 I)} // Simplify`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks for that - I didn't think of using ReplaceAll with the Real and Imaginary parts in terms of the variable and its conjugate. I played with Replace but couldn't get things to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I replace x + I y by z to get the equivalent 2 I z + 3 ?

If I understand you right

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
expr = 3 + 2 I x - 2 y;
Simplify[expr, {x + I*y == z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I always forget that Simplify has a way of specifying this sort of thing. Much appreciated.